# Format Array Tree with Custom ID in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array I need formatted into a single array.  The current function I have works well aside for I can't figure out how to set a custom key for the ID.  The array is used to populate a select box, so I need that ID.  I spent hours messing with it and I am just lost when it comes to formatting arrays.

I need the output to use a custom key (eg. $row->id ) which would output something like:

```
[40 =>'Florida', 50 =>'CA', 33 => 'NY']
```

Right now it outputting like..

```
[0 =>'Florida', 1 =>'CA', 2 => 'NY']
```

This is my current function:

```
protected function createRegionList($parent_id = '0', $spacing = '')
{

    $arr = [];
    foreach ($this->getByParentId($parent_id) as $row) {
        $arr[] = $spacing . '&nbsp;' . $row->title;
        $arr = array_merge($arr, $this->createRegionList($row->id, '&nbsp;' . $spacing . '&mdash;'));
    }
    return $arr;

}
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. I have found a bunch of examples, but they are more multidimensional arrays and I need the output as a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set array item key by specifying the key in brackets. See [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Try this

```
$arr[$row->id] = $spacing . '&nbsp;' . $row->title;
```

[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is not preserving keys. Use [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php).

Or just union these together

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($this->getByParentId($parent_id) as $row) {
    $arr[] = $spacing . '&nbsp;' . $row->title;
    $childs = $this->createRegionList($row->id, '&nbsp;' . $spacing . '&mdash;');
    $arr = $childs + $arr;
}
return $arr;
```

Comment: Thanks,  yeah I tried setting the ID there, but it makes no difference, it just loops over itself setting it back to    [0 =>'Florida', 1 =>'CA', 2 => 'NY']